# Weird behavior when using Instagram hooks for iOS

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

We have an app which shares images to Instagram using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. This works perfectly fine, and as intended once our app hands over the image to Instagram app, the user is greeted with the following screen (See attached screenshot below).

[image: intended behavior]

However, since last week, one of our users running iOS 10.3.2 with latest Instagram app came across this following screen when the app image sharing steps were recreated.

[image: weird behavior]

It appears Instagram lets the user to choose whether to use the image provided by third party app (in this case, our app) either as an Instagram story or to post it to user's Instagram feed.

So far, this has only happened to one particular user. Our attempts to recreate this scenario using the same iPhone device/iOS/Instagram version have all proved unsuccessful.

I have looked into Instagram's iOS SDK documentation as well, and I didn't come across any updates that would explain this behavior.

My questions are, has anyone come across this behavior? Is Instagram testing some new iPhone hooks? Is there anyway to enforce the desired behavior? Any help on this matter is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe they're doing some a/b testing?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using in order to share it?